# Aptana 3 Views have dark backgrounds

Tags: aptana

This is the only part that doesn't fit so well with my favorite text editor.

I need to change the background of the view's (ie. Outline, Properites, Project Explorer, ...). I've tried changing themes from Default to Eclipse, but nothing removes the dark backgrounds there. Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window > Preferences > Aptana > Themes - choose what you like :)

Comment: You can then select/change the background color (and many others) to what you want/like...

Comment: Ah, after close inspection I unchecked "Enable Invasive Themes".There was my answer all along.

Comment: @GraphicAgenda please explain where you have seen it..I mean "Enable Invasive Themes"..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can change it by selecting from "**Overall Theme**" option.